# Ruby on rails gem to show one-time messages to a user.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are there any gems or libraries that can be used to show a message once to a user? I'm looking in particular for something that allows me to:

- Display a "welcome aboard" full overlay when the user logs in for the first time. (And only on the first time)
- A smaller drop down overlay that informs users that there may be maintenance in the next 24 hours, or they need to do something (fill in their profile, etc). This would display until dismissed.

I'm a bit stuck with this, because I don't know what these kind of messages are commonly called. Do these kind of one-time messages have a name?

Comment: Why don't you either create a messages table and store stuff like that in there and/or use cookies to track if you already have displayed the  message. Cookies vene give you that kind of time related info and can be set to vanish after a set time.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a gem to already do this. I could do it myself, but if someone has already created a gem for it, then I may as well use that.

Answer (score 3):

there are many ways to implement such a notification system, your requirements are pretty basic so I'll stick with a basic approach using `flash`

**Show Message on the first login:**

You should keep track of ther user's last login and maybe count the logins, so what you could do:

- Add a field "last_login_at" to your User Model which gets updated every time the user logs in, set it to NULL after registration. When the user logs in you check if the `last_login_at` is NULL if yes you set a message to the flash like `flash[:first_login] = true` then you can render a special welcome message in your template if this flag is set.
- A better approach is to add a field like `login_counter` which gets incremented every time the user logs in, so if it is zero the user is logging in for the first time. A login counter can also help you to identify "active" users who log in often etc.

There is a popular authentication system called devise which has these (and many more!) features built in: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

**Show maintenance warnings etc.**

I'd create a new model called `SystemMessage` which has fields like:

`id | message_type | title | body | valid_from | valid_until`

The `message_type` attribute describes what kind of message it is like "maintenace notice", "new features" etc. dependent on the type of the message you could render different templates and adjust the look of the message.

The `valid_from` and `valid_until` attributes lets you control in which time frame the message should appear.

On every request you fetch these messages and show them to the user, you can also cache the messages on a regular basis to reduce the amount of queries. Have a look at the rails guide about caching: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

To inform users that are idle on a page you can implement an AJAX request which fires every five minutes or so and fetches the messages and checks if there are any messages newer than the ones already displayed.

If you need to show user-specific messages (like you got 5 new mails, someone commented on your post etc.) in real-time you could use a pub-sub messaging system like 'Faye' (tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye or just google for "rails 3 faye")

I hope this is a starting point for you :)